# How to avoid Spike Arrest Limits when making API calls from APEX

Tags: apex, api

I'm running into a problem where my APEX code is firing too many API calls in the span of 100ms, so simply, is there a way to delay the code from firing for 101ms.

As I understand there may be a few 'Bad Code' workarounds such as home brew sleep methods and running for loops until certain conditions have been met, but I would rather avoid these for obvious reasons.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What is the delay that you want to add ? You can explore chaining of queueble jobs which should give you good delay between subsequent api calls.

Comment: I need to space out API calls by just 101ms

Comment: I would not suggest to that because there are other limits in salesforce which will catch up and you would be trying to solve those. In this specific implementation does this gets initiated via page ? If yes then you can make looping api calls after success of each one via JavaScript.

Comment: The worst case scenario I can think of is that you can add the delay by calling getContent to some internal vf page. That should give you delay that you expect. Might want to try with different pages though.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful insight Kiran, My use case is to create an Account as well as Contacts in an external system. I've created a lightning component that on user click, will send 1 external API call to create an account and pimary contact (this is one command) then another API call per other contact on the account in salesforce. So for instance, If i have an account with 1 primary contact and 3 other contacts, this will take 4 api calls to complete. Unfortunately the company I'm working with doesnt have a command for bulk insert of contacts.

Comment: In ideal world other api should not complain about calls between 100 ms. anyway i feel you can take simpler option of making multiple sequential calls from javascript thats a short solution. Or have a middleware like mule to do the api calls add delay and everything but thats a whole lot of new things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your comments, use JavaScript to make the API calls. You can call a wire method, precisely wait at least 101 ms (or any other value), then continue. As a practical example:

```
createPrimaryAccountAndContact({data:data})
.then(result => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 101)))
.then(result => createContact({data:data2}));
```

You'll need a second method to chain together the calls for creating contacts, but this should help get you started, I think.